# React Native can't use custom font with Expo Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

I am trying to use a Google font in my app and have followed the documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts.html) with no luck. I downloaded the font and used the file structure Expo recommended. The docs say to use `async componentDidMount` which you can see I am doing in the code below. I have seen other people have success with using `async componentWillMount` but it has not worked for me.

The error message I get is:

`console.error: "fontFamily 'anton-regular' is not a system font and has not been loaded through Expo.Font.LoadAsync."`

My console.log of `fonts loaded:  true` pops up in the remote debugger right before I get the font error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Font } from 'expo';
import...

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { fontLoaded: false };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'anton-regular': require('./assets/fonts/Anton-Regular.ttf'),
      });
      this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
      console.log('fonts are loaded');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.fontLoaded) {
      console.log('fonts loaded: ', this.state.fontLoaded)
      return (
        <Root>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <AppWithNavigationState />
          </Provider>
        </Root>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Root>
        <LoadingScreen />
      </Root>
    );
  }
}
```

***EDIT***

Per Evan Bacon's suggestion I wrapped the `Font.loadAsyc` in a try/catch but no error was caught. I also added the following to my app.json with no change.

```
 "packagerOpts": {
   "assetExts": ["ttf"]
 },
```

Comment: I suspect the font is failing to download, can you wrap the `Font.loadAsync` with a try/catch and print the error. Also remember to add "ttf" to your `packagerOpts.assetExts` in `app.json` 

Comment: @EvanBacon what this about `packagerOpts.assetExts`? I didn't see anything about that in the docs

Comment: in expo you need to define all of the asset extensions in the app.json. "ttf" might be one of the predefined ones but in snack it exports with it in the app.json

Comment: @EvanBacon just updated the question with your suggestions. Still no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Turns out I had a trailing space in one of the places I was using the font, like so:

`<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'anton-regular ' }}>I'm dumb.</Text>`

Interestingly, I can remove this from `app.json`

```
"packagerOpts": {
  "assetExts": ["ttf"]
},
```

And the font still works.